# Service Executor Problem With Python Calls

Tags: java, python-3.x, executorservice, concurrent.futures

While running concurrent tests (learning about concurrency), the class that suppose to compute a result of a search is not returning during a python call.

This behavior only happens when I setup a test as below, and other tests (one request without executor services, etc) complete without any issues.

What can cause this issue given the setup below?

```
  @Test
  public void concurrent() {

  CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean();
  AtomicInteger overlaps = new AtomicInteger();

  int threads = 1;
  ExecutorService service =
  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

  Collection<Future<Integer>> futures =
    new ArrayList<>(threads);

  for (int t = 0; t < threads; ++t) {
    futures.add(
      service.submit(
        () -> {
          //  latch.await();
          if (running.get()) {
            overlaps.incrementAndGet();
          }
          running.set(true);
          FAEnvironmentSizeDescriptor sizeDesc = compute(payload);
          running.set(false);
          return null;
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The python callout in the class is pretty standard:

```
pbExec = new ProcessExec(pb, output, stdin, true);
```

Also tried with `Process` and for some reason it's not returning when running the tests.